# Reference collapsing?

Tags: c++, reference-collapsing

By trying to solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769781/stdpair-of-references), something made me wonder. Consider the following code:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo 
{
    foo(T const& x) : data(x) {}
    T data;
};
```

It seems that I can construct an object of type `foo<T const&>` without error, the hypothetical `T const& const&` being understood as `T const&`.

It seems also that this is called *reference collapsing*, but I never heard this term before (see comments in the linked question).

Is this widespread? Is this standard?

Comment: +1.  I have some homework to do on this, thx

Comment: I would like to link this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144234/c-template-instantiation-with-reference-type

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In C++03, it was not legal to do the following

```
typedef int &ref;
ref &r = ...; // reference to reference!
```

This frequently causes problems for people compiling with really strict or older C++03 compilers  (GCC4.1 as well as Comeau 8/4/03 do not like the above) because the Standard function object binders do not take care of the "reference to reference" situation, and occasionally create such illegal types.

In C++0x this is called "reference collapsing", yes. Most current C++03 compilers do that (i.e a `T&` where `T` denotes a reference type is `T` again), by retroactively applying the rule. The [boost.call_traits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/utility/call_traits.htm) library makes it easy to declare such function parameters though, so that the "reference to reference" situation does not occur.

Please note that the `const` there does not have any effect. A `const` applied on a reference type is silently ignored. So even if the compiler supports reference collapsing, the following is not legal

```
int const x = 0;

// illegal: trying to bind "int&" to "int const"!
ref const& r = x;
```

Comment: Great, I figured out this could be solved by traits classes, but I have never seen any such thing in [my implementation of] STL.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "i.e. a `T&` where `T` denotes a reference type is `T&` again"?

Comment: @Fred that would be self-recursive. I mean, if `T` is `U&`, and you say `T&`, the result type is `T` - i.e `U&`. Of course, this is not compatible with rvalue references. I would need to say "i.e a `T&` where `T` denotes a type `U &-or-&&` denotes the type `U &`", to be correct with rvalue refs.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=311), in C++98 there was only limited support for reference collapsing:

> In C++98, there is only one reference
>   collapsing rule: T& & or a reference
>   to a reference, collapses to T&:

```
void g(int & ri) {++ri;} // int& & -> int& 
void f(int & ri) {g(ri);}
```

Even there, it's illegal to try to declare a variable that is a reference to a reference:

```
int ben;
int& bill(ben);     // OK
int & & bob(bill);  // error C2529: 'bob' : reference to reference is illegal
```

Comment: There is no reference collapsing in C++03. The author of that article is misguided. The type of an identity-expression using the name of a reference is not a reference type. *No* expression has reference type. Expressions have value categories which decide how they may bind to references.

Comment: @Potatoswatter - thanks, and also there are better references now.  I'll delete this part.

Comment: Thanks… but hmm, that link isn't the one I followed before.

Comment: @Potatoswatter - I removed a link to MSDN that had refs to C++03

Comment: The link you removed isn't the one I was referring to in the first comment. The example is mistaken; the function call `g( ri )` doesn't involve any sort of collapsing.