# C++ - template instantiation with reference type

Tags: c++, templates

I've heard a little bit about reference-to-reference problem and [this](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/iso/cwg_defects.html#106) resolution. I'm not very good with C++ Committee terminology, but I understand the "Moved to DR" annotation in the link means that this is the current interpretation that standard-conforming compilers should adhere to.

I have this sample code that I can't understand:

```
template <typename T>
struct C {
  void f(T&) { }
  void f(const T&) { }
};

int main() {
  C<int> x;        // OK
  C<int&> y;       // compile error: f cannot be overloaded
  C<const int&> z; // compile error: f cannot be overloaded
}
```

I understand the error in `C<const int&>` case: using rules from DR #106 we get two methods with the same signature f(const int&). What I don't get is the `C<int&>` case: shouldn't it generate exactly the same code as `C<int>` (at least according to Stroustrup's resolution)?

Comment: vs2010 generate the same error (while vs2008 report a ref-to-ref illegal error)

Comment: this has something to do with the fact that dynamic/static cast is not allowed with references to types. "'doubl& d = dynamic_cast<double&>(someintvariable)'" leads to 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'double &' in MSVC

Comment: @Bahadir Turkmen  but in the case of C<int&> y, I didn't see value-to-reference cast

Comment: I think "DR status" just means that the relevant committee agrees that it is a defect in the standard. I don't think it means that the proposed solution must be adopted by conforming compilers, just that the actual standard is flawed. Could be wrong, I'm not a standards committee follower. If nothing else, the rules of ISO dictate that resolutions of a WG can't modify the standard without a proper vote of ISO member organizations, IIRC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DR only means "Defect Report", and to my knowledge, the described resolution hasn't made it (yet) to the standard. For this reason, I believe a strictly conforming C++03 implementation should not compile this code because of it is forming a reference to a reference.

[Edit] Just found a [nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771208/reference-collapsing/3772234#3772234) on this issue.

Comment: Another interesting read : http://groups.google.com/group/comp.std.c++/browse_thread/thread/ac9ba419a0d95b2d

Comment: Thanks, this nicely explains compiler's behaviour in all cases mentioned by me and Steve Townsend.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, when I compile your code (Visual C++ 10 Express) I get errors, but also when I try this simpler case:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
  C<int> x;        // OK
  C<const int> x1; // error C2535: 'void C<T>::f(T &)' : member function 
                   // already defined or declared
  return 0;
}
```

Seems like the ref-to-ref collapsing defined in the DR you mentioned means that `const` ref becomes a simple non-const ref within the template.  My problem with this is that I don't understand why the second `f` is not just ignored.

If I change C so that the second f is `const`-qualified, this now compiles:

```
template <typename T>
struct C {
  void f(T&) { }
  void f(const T& t) const {}
};
```

The implication seems to be that when `C` is  instantiated with `const` anything (ref or not), the two `C::f` overloads are simply identical, and result in compile-time duplicate detection.

Perhaps somebody smarter than me can decipher the chain more definitively here.

EDIT: On reflection, it's not surprising here that `T = const int&` results in the `f` overloads being identically instantiated as

```
void f(const int&) {}
```

That's what the compiler is telling me:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

template <typename T>
struct C {
  void f(T&) { }
  void f(const T&) { }
};

int main() {
  C<const int&> z; // compile error: f cannot be overloaded
  return 0;
}
```

gives this error:

```
1>test.cpp(6): error C2535: 'void C<T>::f(T)' : member function already 
    defined or declared
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=const int &
1>          ]
1>          test.cpp(5) : see declaration of 'C<T>::f'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=const int &
1>          ]
1>          test.cpp(10) : see reference to class template instantiation 
                'C<T>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=const int &
1>          ]
```

I'm not even convinced this has anything to do with the DR.

Comment: Now I think it is weird... Your example in fact has nothing to do with ref-to-ref; while C<int&> in the question has nothing to do with const...

Comment: @lz_prgmr - I am not even sure is my example is relevant apart from the identical compiler error it generates. I am hoping to move the discussion along some, is all. I guess if a particular `T` genuinely resolves to both `f` overloads, the compiler error is expected - it would not ignore an equally-good match. Why are they each considered 'equally good', is the question I cannot answer.