# const references in c++ templates

Tags: c++, templates, reference, constants

In a C++ template with the generic type T, I can use

```
const T &
```

to get a reference to a constant T. However, if now T itself is a reference type (like e.g. T = int &), the above term resolves to

```
int &
```

and not to

```
const int &
```

which quite makes sense, since any reference itself is always constant. However, is there still a way to require a

```
const T &
```

if T itself is a reference type?

Edit: sample code to evaluate (g++ compiler):

```
template <typename T> class TemplateClass
{
public:
    void foo(const T &bar) { }
};

int main()
{
    TemplateClass<int &> x;
    x.foo(0);   // <-- compile error: no conversion from int to int&
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it resolves to `int&`.  Why do you think that it does?

Comment: @MathiasKunter: What makes you think g++ says it does?

Comment: @NicolBolas: actually it seems that he's right... http://ideone.com/h7PsC

Comment: see edited question for example code

Comment: *But*: Comeau says that it's incorrect. So, probably it's a g++ bug.

Comment: @MathiasKunter: You should put that code in your question, not a comment.

Comment: GCC is (even in pedantic mode, apparently?) allowing this by extension. A reference to a reference should be an error, and reference collapsing rules weren't introduced until C++11. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771208/reference-collapsing).

Comment: `std::add_const` doesn't seem to work:  http://ideone.com/gwUSV

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Remove the reference:

```
template<typename T>
void Test(const typename std::remove_reference<T>::type & param)
{
        param = 20;
}
```

Now it works as expected.

Comment: This is both awesome, and messed up.

Answer (score 10):

You can always use template specialisation to implement a different version for any kind of reference:

```
template <typename T> struct X {
  void foo(T const&);
};

template <typename T> struct X<T&> {
  void foo(T const&);
};
```

Now, `X<int>::foo` expects an `int const&` and `X<int&>::foo` expects an `int const&`, too.

However, it is not entirely clear from your question what you are trying to do exactly.

---

Edit: My g++ version (4.6.1) does not complain without template specialisation for the following

```
int i = 7;
X<int&>(i);
```

While it does for

```
X<int&>(7);
```

Which is correct IMO, because you try to convert a temporary (`7`) to a mutable reference (even if that is a reference to a const reference).

---

Edit 2: If you want to reduce duplicate code, then do not specialise your original class, but use this:

```
template <typename T> struct R {
  typedef T& Ref;
  typedef T const& ConstRef;
};

template <typename T> struct R<T&> {
  typedef T& Ref;
  typedef T const& ConstRef;
};

template<typename T> struct X {
  void foo(typename R<T>::ConstRef x);
};
```

Comment: Yes this would indeed solve the problem. I however would like to preserve the overhead of using a template specialization if possible.

Comment: Yes, what I'm trying to achieve is that `X<int&>(7)` is also valid (which it would be if the parameter's type was a `const int &` instead of `int &`). But it seems that template specialisation is the only way to go here, right?

Comment: @MathiasKunter: Yes. Either use my minimal `R` type (change name for production code) or `std::remove_reference` which presumably does precisely the same trick (but there you would have to add `const&` yourself).

Comment: Okay just saw your second edit. Thanks, that sould make it. Great solution IMHO.

Comment: @ildjarn How would you specialize that function?

Comment: Ah, my mistake -- the member function can be explicitly specialized, but not partially specialized, so that doesn't directly help with this scenario. Apologies for the noise. :-]

Comment: @MathiasKunter: You can use traits as per the second edit, but those are implemented in terms of specializations... but at least it will remove the need for duplicate implementations. You can use `typename const std::remove_reference<T>::type &` as your argument type (I would recommend using a typedef for that...

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the very same problem. It seems that the '&' type conversion operator binds stronger than the 'const' qualifier. So when we have this code:

```
template<class t>
void fun(const t i)
{
}

fun<int&>();
```

the function ends up with type *void(int&)*, not the expected *void(const int&)*.

To solve this problem, I have defined this template:

```
template<class t> struct constify { typedef t type; };
template<class t> struct constify<t&> { typedef const t& type; };
```

Now define your function as:

```
template<class t>
void fun(typename constify<t>::type i)
{
}

fun<int&>();
```

The instantiated function will have the type *void(const int&)*, as needed.