# why can not add low-level const type to local variable in template function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I'm studying c++ template, and write a example as shown below:

```
  #include <vector>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <type_traits>
  #include <typeinfo>

  using namespace std;

  template <typename T>
  void fcn(T &&val)
  {
      cout << is_same<T, int&>::value << endl;
      const T t = val;
      //T const t = val;
      cout << typeid(t).name() << endl;
      t = 10;
      cout << "val: " << val;
      cout << ", t: " << t << endl;
      return;
  }

  int main()
  {
      cout << boolalpha;

      int i{};

      fcn(i);
   }
```

I expect this code can't compile successfully, but there are no error, the output:

```
true
i
val: 10, t: 10
```

I have two questions:

1. gcc deduce the T is `int& type`, the line `const T t = val`, means t const bind to val, like this: `const int &t = val`, why the const has no effect? t and i value can be changed?
2. I used `typeid(t).name()`to show the t's type, why just print `i`?

Answer (score 3):

1. In your case, `const T` with `T = int&` means, g*ive a reference which I can't reassign*. But a reference is never assignable, it always points to the same object. So it collapses to `T`, which is in that case `int&`.

To make it works as expected, used `std::remove_reference`

See : [const references in c++ templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302638/const-references-in-c-templates)

2. `name` returns something that is implementation-defined, so there is not much to say about it.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. gcc deduce the `T` is `int&` type, `const T t = val`, means t const bind to val, why the `const` has no effect?

This function template signature

```
template <typename T> void fcn(T &&val);
```

uses a forwarding reference. In short, when deducing the instantiation with an lvalue `int` (your case), you end up with `T = int&`, i.e., including the reference. Reference collapsing transformes `void fcn(T& &&val)` to `void fcn(T& val)`.

When you declare `const T t`, this means `T& const` (`const` modifies what's on its left, and if there is nothing on its left, it modifies what's on its right). But this isn't valid as there is no such thing as a `const`-qualified reference, hence the `const`-qualifier is dropped.

> 2. I used `typeid(t).name()` to show the t's type, why just print `i`?

`typeid(t).name()` isn't required to output a human readable identifier. `i` stands for `int`, so depending on the compiler, this is what you should expect. When working with `clang` or `gcc`, it is however often nicer to display a type through

```
template <class T> p(T&&) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__; }

p(t); // prints out understandable type info
```

Comment: 1. I think const modifies what's on the right, when the left.

Comment: 2. thans a lot your suggestion, the __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ look better.

Answer (score 0):

I write another program to research `const T` which using "type alias":

```
  #include <iostream>                                                                                 

  using namespace std; 

  int main()                                                                                          
  {
    int i {};
    using T = int *;                                                                                
    const T t = &i;     // same with T const t = &i;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

    *t = 10;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    cout << i << endl;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    int j{};                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    //t = &j;   // error, t is int * const                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  }
```

it compile successfully, output: `10`.

now I can understand why compiler considers `const T` is `int * const`, but not `const int *`, because that compiler treats `T` as a common type like `int`, `char`, not `int *`, it is not substitution.