# Reference collapsing under C++03

Tags: visual-c++-2008, c++03

I need to create a predicate from bound member function, so I wrapped it in a `boost::function<bool(SomeObject const &)>`. That seems to be fine and everything, but I also needed to negate it in one case. However

```
boost::function<bool(SomeObject const &)> pred;
std::not1(pred);
```

does not compile under MSVC++ 9.0 (Visual Studio 2008), complaining that reference to reference is invalid:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\functional(213) : warning C4181: qualifier applied to reference type; ignored
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\functional(213) : error C2529: '_Left' : reference to reference is illegal
```

The problem is that `boost::function` defines the `argument_type` as `SomeObject const &` and the `std::unary_negate<_Fn1>` instantiated by `std::not1` internally tries to use `const typename _Fn1::argument_type&` and compiler rejects it because `T::argument_type` is already a reference. I am certain that that should compile under C++11, but this is old compiler that is C++03 only. So I'd like to know who's fault it is:

- the compiler's, because it should collapse the reference [(apparently not)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3772234/201725),
- the standard library's, because it should be prepared to handle functors taking references (apparently not, because the specification defines `unary_negate` with `const typename Predicate::argument_type& x` argument),
- boost's, because `argument_type` shouldn't be reference even when the actual argument is or
- mine, because `boost::function` shouldn't be used with reference arguments?

Comment: Does it compile under other compilers?

Comment: @eh9: With gcc it compiles, at least for mingw32 and cygwin targets.

Comment: @eh9: But it's not too relevant for the question; who's fault it is and why depends on the specification.

Comment: @eh9: Actually, no, it does not compile with gcc with `-ansi`.

Comment: I ask because I had problems a few years ago with MSVC++, probably the same version you're using. In my case it was a quite subtle problem with template point-of-instantiation and some triply-nested and partly self-referential template usage. I had been relying on the compiler to help me understand some of the minutiae, and it was lying to me.

Comment: @eh9: In this case there seems to be mismatch between what standard library does (use base types in `argument_type` and const reference in the argument) and what boost does (use references only when part of the type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fault is certainly not Boost's; `boost::function` is basically just `std::function`, with all the same semantics. And `boost::function`s with reference parameters work fine, too. You just can't use them with `std::not1` or the rest of the `<functional>` stuff.

C++11's reference-collapsing makes `std::not1` work the way you would think it ought to. The way `std::not1` was specified in C++03 couldn't possibly work without reference-collapsing — except in implementations where the implementors did a little bit of creative interpretation rather than slavishly following the letter of the Standard.

It's *possible* to make `std::not1` work in C++03 by adding a specialization of `std::unary_negate` for predicates with reference `argument_type`s, but neither libc++ nor libstdc++ has done so.

But you know who has? **Boost!** If you just change your code to use `boost::not1` everywhere you currently use `std::not1`, [everything will work fine.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/libs/functional/negators.html#arguments) Basically, think of the `boost` namespace as if it were a C++11-compliant version of `std`; anything that works in C++11's `std` namespace probably works in C++03's `boost` namespace.

---

Caveat, hopefully off-topic: The Clang compiler on my Macbook (`Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)`) silently collapses references even in `-std=c++03` mode, so that

```
typedef const int& ref;
typedef const ref& ref2;
```

produces no error. When you test your C++03 code, make sure you're not using a compiler with this misfeature.