# What happens when there are extra modifiers for a type?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771208/reference-collapsing)

```
template<
    class T = const std::vector<int> &
> void f(const T &);
```

If `T` is already `const` and a reference, what will happen? Why does this code compile then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be the equivalent of `const (const std::vector<int>&)`&, and in this case, the `const` would be ignored since you cannot have a const reference to const T, only reference to const T. Since references cannot be reseated, the `const` would be redundant anyway. Also, ignoring the `const` you have `(T&) &`, and due to reference collapsing rules in C++11, this becomes `T&`. So the end result is `const T&` or `const std::vector<int>&` in your case.

If you had `const T*`, then it would make a difference since that would be `const (const std::vector<int>&)* p` which would make the pointer `const`.

Comment: Good answer, one quest: What are const lvalue references?

Comment: In C++11, rvalue references where introduced (`int&&`), so C++03 references (`int&`) are called `lvalue references` now.

Comment: Okay. I just didn't get the terminology there. :)

Comment: @user2030677: My wording was bad, so I changed it.