# Is std::min returning an lval standard?

Tags: c++

On gcc 4.7.2, I can write:

```
int x = 1, y = 2;
std::min<int&>(x,y) = 3;
```

And that compiles and ends up assigning 3 to `x`. But every reference I can find for `std::min` says it returns a `const T&`. So is this behavior standard or not?

Comment: FWIW, this doesn't compile for me with Clang or GCC (4.9).

Comment: @chris Oh, that has an interesting reason. But you can explicitly select the overload, to prevent instantiation of the `initializer_list` overload: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/58f716bd998032a6

Comment: @dyp, Good point. The error didn't click that it was because of compiling with C++11 and adding those overloads.

Comment: @dyp That still won't compile on clang though. So does that mean this is non-standard and gcc just happens to support it?

Comment: @Barry Unless it is forbidden to explicitly provide the template argument (instead of letting the compiler deduce it), libc++'s implementation has a bug: it dispatches `min` to the form with an explicit comparator: `_VSTD::min(__a, __b, __less<_Tp>())` the template parameter `_Tp` is used for the comparator, but not explicitly passed to the other `min` function called; therefore the other `min` will deduce `_Tp` to be `int` (without `&`) -- i.e. the type of the function parameter and the type expected by the comparator don't match.

Comment: @dyp - so yes standard, but in some cases incorrectly unsupported?

Comment: Unfortunately, I currently don't have the time to answer thoroughly. The example you present is ill-formed; I think the example I've shown is well-formed.

Comment: This isn't valid C++03 code either, because it doesn't have reference collapsing, and you can't form references to reference. So the code as presented in the question will only work with an implementation that implements C++11 reference collapsing but not the full C++11 standard library...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Why it's not legal

There are four `std::min` function templates in C++11 [algorithms.general]/2:

```
template<class T>
const T& min(const T& a, const T& b);

template<class T, class Compare>
const T& min(const T& a, const T& b, Compare comp);

template<class T               > T min(initializer_list<T> t);
template<class T, class Compare> T min(initializer_list<T> t, Compare comp);
```

(I'm not sure if for the purpose of taking a pointer, there might be additional overloads.)

To simplify the notation, I'll use ["continental const placement"](http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/17/continental-const-placement/) from here on:

```
template<class T>
T const& min(T const& a, T const& b);
```

When explicitly providing the first template argument as in `std::min<int&>(x,y)`,
all of those overloads are tried to be instantiated. For those where instantiation succeeds, overload resolution selects the viable candidates, then a single best match. If instantiation (substitution) for any of those overloads fails in a non-immediate context, an error occurs.

Since you pass `int&` as the template argument, `T` in all the overloads above will be substituted for `int&`. This can lead to instantiating `initializer_list<T>` (if the compiler can determine the correct overload without instantiating this class, it doesn't have to).

Overload resolution must check if the conversion from an lvalue of type `int` (the argument) to `initializer_list<int&>` is valid. This requires instantiating the class, to check for converting constructors. (As I said, if the compiler is smart enough, it does not have to perform this instantiation.)

The compilers I've checked - including g++4.9 and clang++3.5, in both libstdc++ and libc++ - report an error for `std::min<int&>(x,y)`. This error occurs due to trying to instantiate `initializer_list<int&>`: there is a member defined as follows

```
typedef E const* iterator;
```

where `E` is the template parameter of the `initializer_list`. Substituting `E` for `int&` yields

```
typedef int& const* iterator;
```

which illegally forms a pointer to a reference.

The definition of the member is not in an immediate context of `std::min`, therefore an error occurs (the program is ill-formed).

---

### Working around the problem

We can however eliminate this problem by specifying explicitly which overload to call. This can be done by using a function pointer (which requires overload resolution to get a pointer to a single function):

```
using ft = int&(int&,int&);
constexpr auto f = static_cast<ft*>(&std::min<int&>);
auto const min = f(x,y);
```

This works fine in libstdc++, but fails in libc++. I cannot find any text that forbids explicitly providing the template argument to `std::min`, nor can I find any requirement that the template argument must not be a reference.

How does it work? The cast explicitly selects an overload. A special kind of overload resolution is performed, that selects only the overload(s) whose type is *identical* to `ft`. This might require an instantiation of the overload of `std::min` which takes a `initializer_list`, but it does not require an instantiation of `initializer_list<int&>`. When comparing to the implicit overload resolution in a call-expression such as `std::min<int&>(x,y)`, note that we do not need to convert from some type to `intializer_list<int&>` here: we only need to check whether `initializer_list<int&>` (the type of the first parameter of the function) is the same type as `int&` (the type of the first parameter of `ft`).

I conclude therefore that the above code is well-formed and well-behaved. This implies that there's a bug in libc++. For those interested, [libc++ dispatches](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/algorithm#L2581) the first `std::min` overload (with two parameter of the form `const&`) to the form with a predicate/comparator:

```
template <class _Tp>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR_AFTER_CXX11
const _Tp&
min(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b)
{
    return _VSTD::min(__a, __b, __less<_Tp>());
}
```

The problem here is that the template parameter is not explicitly passed to the other `std::min` function, but deduced. However, the deduced type is `int`, not `int&`. This produces a mismatch between the function parameter types `int const&` and the type expected by the comparator `int&`:

```
bool less(int&, int&);

int const& min(int const& x, int const& y)
{
    return less(y, x) ? y : x; // cannot bind an lvalue of type `int const`
                               // to a parameter of type `int&`
}
```

---

### Assigning to `min(x,y)`

When we instantiate the first `std::min` overload via `std::min<int&>` and `int&` is substituted, [*reference collapsing*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3772234/420683) happens:

In the initial `T const&` parameter type, `T` is substituted for `int&`. This yields `int& const&`. The `const&` is collapsed with the `int&` to the type `int&`. The signature of the instantiated function becomes:

```
int& min<int&>(int& a, int& b);
```

Therefore, with the above definition of `f`, we can write:

```
f(x, y) = 42;
```

---

### Value category

If the return type of a function is an lvalue-reference, the function call expression is an lvalue. Value category is not concerned with const-ness. `std::min` returns an lvalue in any case.

Comment: Wow. Thank you for taking the time. I wish I could up vote twice.

Comment: Actually question, when you do `f = static_cast<ft*>(&std::min<int&>)`, how does that know to pick the `T const&` version instead of the invalid `initializer_list<T>` version?

Comment: @Barry Because this expression explicitly selects the function(s) whose type is identical to `ft`. It might be subtler than I originally thought, though: Instantiation of the `initializer_list<T>` overload seems to happen, but there is no need to instantiate `initializer_list<int&>` itself to select an overload via casting.