# make_pair of references?

Tags: c++, reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [std::pair of references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769781/stdpair-of-references)

Apparently `make_pair` makes copies of whatever it makes a pair of, see e.g. the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main(void) {
    int i;
    vector<int> v (1), w (1);
    pair<vector<int>, vector<int> > p = make_pair(v, w);
    p.first[0] = 42;
    for (i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        cout << v[i] << " ";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        cout << p.first[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

which prints

```
0 42
```

instead of

```
42 42
```

as I would like.

Is there some way to get the other behavior (i.e. have `make_pair` really only store references to whatever it makes a pair of)?

(And optimally, I would like that a function returns this pair to initialize a variable in the caller function, without doing all the extra copying.  If this is relevant info, the returned pair of vectors can/should be declared as `const` in the caller function.)

Yes, I know, I could put pointers to return values as arguments of my functions... but I'd rather not.  And if I really have to do that, I'd much rather have a single return value rather than many at the same time.

Thanks in advance,

Antony

note: edited so that code actually corresponds to output

Comment: Have you tried passing the arguments through `std::forward`?

Comment: Are you certain that it doesn't print `0 0 0 42 0 0` ?

Answer (score 0):

`boost::ref`/`boost::cref`

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/ref.html