# instantiate pair object in C++

Tags: c++11

I have a vertex class with many objects, e.g.

```
class Vertex{
    int i;
public:
    Vertex(const int & a):i(a){}
};

Vertex v1(1),v2(2)...v100(100);
```

Now I want to make 50 pairs, each pair linking two vertices. What is the best way to achieve this? I definitely don't want to do the following:

```
std::pair<const Vertex &, const Vertex &> p1(v1,v2);
...
std::pair<const Vertex &, const Vertex &> p50(v99,v100);
```

std::make_pair seems to be a better choice. But it only accept values, not references, if I understand correctly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Create a vector of type Vertex and iterate over them, pairing every subsequent two?

Comment: how exactly does it work? suppose I have vector<Vertex> v; do I do this: for(i=0;i<=99;i++) std::pair<const Vertex &, const Vertex &>=p(v[i],v[i+1])? I am afraid this will not work since it is using the same "p". Sorry, I am just quite new to C++.

Comment: you have 100 variables???

Comment: Assume I do. Any way to avoid some hard labor?

Comment: Some tips on reference pairs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769781/stdpair-of-references

Comment: @user3348650: Yes!  Use `std::array` (Or maybe `std::vector`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::make_pair` can be used to create pairs of references through the use of `std::ref`. `std::ref` stores a reference in a `std::reference_wrapper`, which through template type deduction, reduces back to the reference. For a `const` reference, use `std::cref`.

As the other answers suggest, I'd recommend storing your `Vertex`es in a `std::vector`, and initialize them in a for loop. Similarly, store your `std::pair`s of `Vertex` references in a vector and construct them in a loop as well.

```
constexpr auto num_vertices = 100;

std::vector<Vertex> v;
v.reserve(num_vertices);
for (auto i = 0; i < num_vertices; ++i)
    v.emplace_back(i);

std::vector<std::pair<const Vertex&, const Vertex&>> p;
p.reserve(num_vertices/2);
for (auto i = 0; i < num_vertices; i += 2)
    p.emplace_back(v[i], v[i+1]);
```

Notice that `emplace_back` is used to construct the `Vertex`es and `std::pair`s in-place.

However, if you are tied to 50 lines of pair initialization, and want to use the type deduction offered by `std::make_pair`, use:

```
auto p1 = std::make_pair(std::cref(v1), std::cref(v2)),
     p2 = std::make_pair(std::cref(v3), std::cref(v4)),
     // ...
     p50 = std::make_pair(std::cref(v99), std::cref(v100));
```

But in this case, it's simpler to just use uniform initialization:

```
std::pair<const Vertex&, const Vertex&> p1 = {v1, v2},
                                        p2 = {v2, v3},
                                        // ...
                                        p50 = {v99, v100};
```

Here's a live example on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/3z6MaX).

Comment: Is there any advantage here to `std::reference_wrapper` over a regular pointer?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a `std::vector` to store your pairs of `Vertex`'s?

```
std::vector<std::pair<Vertex, Vertex>> v;
v.reserve(50); // Reserve memory to avoid unnecessary allocations.

for (int i = 1; i < 100; i += 2) {
    v.emplace_back(i, i + 1); // Create 50 pairs in vector.
}
```

Later access individual vertices like so:

```
auto& p1 = v[0];
/* ... */
auto& p50 = v[49];
```

If you really want to keep 100 variables for all the vertices then you can store constant references to `Vertex` in `std::pair` using [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper):

```
auto p1 = std::make_pair(std::cref(v1), std::cref(v2));
```