# Temporary lifetime and perfect forwarding constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I am having trouble understanding why the lifetime of temporaries bound to const reference parameters is cut short when there is a perfect forwarding constructor around. First of, what we know about temporaries bound to reference parameters: they last for the full expression:

> A temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call (5.2.2) persists until the completion of the full expression containing the call

However I found cases where this is not true (or I might simply misunderstand what a full expression is). Let's take a simple example, first we define an object with verbose constructors and destructors:

```
struct A {
  A(int &&) { cout << "create A" << endl; }
  A(A&&) { cout << "move A" << endl; }
  ~A(){ cout << "kill A" << endl; }
};
```

And an object wrapper B, which will be used for reference collapsing:

```
template <class T> struct B {
  T value;
  B() : value() { cout << "new B" << endl; }
  B(const T &__a) : value(__a) { cout << "create B" << endl; }
  B(const B &p) = default;
  B(B && o) = default;
  ~B(){ cout << "kill B" << endl; };
};
```

We can now use our wrapper to capture references on temporaries and use them in function calls, like so:

```
void foo(B<const A&> a){ cout << "Using A" << endl; }
int main(){ foo( {123} ); }
```

The program above prints what I would expect:

```
create A
create B
Using A
kill B
kill A
```

So far so good. Now let's move back to `B` and add a perfect forwarding constructor for convertible types:

```
template <class T> struct B {
  /* ... */
  template <class U, class = typename enable_if<is_convertible<U, T>::value>::type>
    B(U &&v) : value(std::forward<U>(v)) { 
      cout << "new forward initialized B" << endl; 
    }
};
```

Compiling the same code again now gives:

```
create A
new forward initialized B
kill A
Using A
kill B
```

Note that our `A` object was now killed before it was used, which is bad! Why did the lifetime of the temporary **not** get extended to the full call of `foo` in this case? Also, there is no other call to the desctructor of `A`, so there is no other instance of it.

I can see two possible explanations:

- either the types are not what I think they are: changing the convertible move constructor to `B(T &&v)` instead of `template <class U>B(U &&v)` solves the problem.
- or `{123}` is not a subexpression of `foo( {123} )`. Swapping `{123}` for `A(123)` also solves the issue, which makes me wonder if brace-initializers are full expressions.

Could someone clarify what is going on here?

Does this mean that adding a forwarding constructor to a class could break backward compatibility in some cases, like it did for `B`?

You can find the full code [here](http://ideone.com/BZ6tm4), with another test case crashing for references to strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type inferred for `U` in the call to `B<A const&>::B(U&&)` is `int`, so the only temporary that can be lifetime-extended for the call to `foo` in `main` is a prvalue `int` temporary initialized to `123`.

The member `A const& value` is bound to a temporary `A`, but that `A` is created in the *mem-initializer-list* of the constructor `B<A const&>::B(U&&)` so its lifetime is extended only for the duration of that member initialization **[class.temporary]**/5:

> — A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor’s *ctor-initializer* (12.6.2) persists until the constructor exits.

Note that a *mem-initializer-list* is the part after the colon in a *ctor-initializer*:

```
  template <class U, class = typename enable_if<is_convertible<U, T>::value>::type>
    B(U &&v) : value(std::forward<U>(v)) { 
             ^--- ctor-initializer
               ^--- reference member
                    ^--- temporary A
```

This is why `kill A` is printed *after* `new forward initialized B`.

> Does this mean that adding a forwarding constructor to a class could break backward compatibility in some cases, like it did for `B`?

Yes. In this case it's difficult to see why the forwarding constructor would be necessary; it's certainly dangerous where you have a reference member that a temporary could be bound to.

Comment: Right. It was much simpler than I thought, I should have spotted that. The original problem emerged with `std::pair`, which has a similar constructor to my `B`. I had a function expecting a `const vector<pair<const string&, const string&>>&`, which I naively called like `foo({{"hello","world"},{"foo","bar"}})`, expecting c++03 behavior, only to find out that the strings had disappeared by the time I entered the function. Is there any reported case of move semantics breaking existing code in STL?

Comment: @Thibaut I don't think they though much about `pair` of reference types, since creating a pair of references is illegal in C++03: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769781/stdpair-of-references

Comment: Yes, I was mixing up C++03 with reference collapsing. I was still somehow surprised by the output, it's interesting to know that building a pair of references might create dead temporaries.

Answer (score 3):

```
void foo(B<const A&> b);

foo( {123} );
```

is semantically equivalent to:

```
B<const A&> b = {123};
```

that for a *non-explicit* constructor is semantically equivalent to:

```
B<const A&> b{123};
```

going further, since your *forwarding-constructor* takes anything, it actually is initialized with `int`, not `A`:

```
B<const A&>::B(int&& v)
```

That is, a temporary instance of `A` is created on the constructor's initialization list:

```
B(int&& v) : value(A{v}) {}
//    created here ^      ^ destroyed here
```

which is *legal*, just like you can type `const A& a{123};`.

This `A` instance is destroyed after the `B`'s construction is finished, and you end up with a *dangling reference* within the body of `foo`.

The situation changes when you build the instance in a call expression, then the `A` temporary ends its lifetime at the end of the call expression:

```
 foo( A{123} );
 //           ^ A is destroyed here
```

so it stays alive within `foo`, and the *forwarding-constructor* selected for `B<const A&>` is instantiated with a type `A&&`.