# Why can I not compile a unique_ptr<pair<int, int&>>

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to create a pair where one of the two items of the pair is a reference. If I attempt to have a unique ptr to this pair I get an error message from utility saying cannot convert int to int&.

I understand that I couldn't have a default constructed pair but my intention (by putting it in a ptr) is to only new it when I have something for that int to refer too.

```
unique_ptr<pair<int, int&>> uptr; // Full error posted below
shared_ptr<pair<int, int&>> sptr; // Compiles fine
```

Full Error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\utility(145) : error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'int &'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\utility(142) : while compiling class template member function 'std::_Pair_base<_Ty1,_Ty2>::_Pair_base(int &&,int &&)'
with
[
    _Ty1=int,
    _Ty2=int &
]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\utility(174) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Pair_base<_Ty1,_Ty2>' being compiled
with
[
    _Ty1=int,
    _Ty2=int &
]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\memory(2161) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' being compiled
with
[
    _Ty1=int,
    _Ty2=int &
]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\memory(2195) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Unique_ptr_base<_Ty,_Dx,_Empty_deleter>' being compiled
with
[
    _Ty=std::pair<int,int &>,
    _Dx=std::default_delete<std::pair<int,int &>>,
    _Empty_deleter=true
]
myClass.h(99) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>' being compiled
with
[
    _Ty=std::pair<int,int &>
]
```

I would have thought that this would compile, and can't work out why anything is being initialized on this line, or where that non ref int is coming from.

Comment: use ```std::reference_wrapper``` if VS 2010 has it.

Comment: I get no problems compiling this with VS 2012 - consider upgrading? :)

Comment: Works fine with GCC 4.9.2 also.

Comment: @onqtam: Upgrade? In our moment of triumph?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3769781/560648

Comment: I have no power over things like what compiler we use unfortunately :-(