# A more elegant way than using classes to store pointers that will receive their value in the future?

Tags: c++, pointers

I use this class to be able to set a pointer later in a process like this:

```
class PointerContainer{
    public: float* FPointer;
}
```

I create a relation that will be executed in the future between the `PointerContainter` and a float variable that will be created in some place:

```
class FutureRelation{
    PointerContainer PContainer;
    int FloatSlot;
}

PointerContainer somePointerContainer;
FutureRelation connection;
connection.PContainer= somePointerContainer;
connection.FloatSlot=5;
```

When the object that has the float I want to connect is created I resolve the connection:

```
connection.PContainer.FPointer = &FloatNumberInThe5thSlotOfSomeObject;
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this without using the PointerContainer class?

Note: The FutureRelation objects are meant to be deleted once they are performed, so the pointer can't be stored on those.

EDIT:
This question ended up being an incomplete version of the question I wanted to ask because I didn't describe the whole scenario but anyways it is a complete question by itself and I think it has a proper answer (the marked one).

That being said, the answer given to this question made me temporarily conclude that there is no cheaper container for a float pointer than a class, so I ended up not pre-defining some variable connections and just linking them after all the necessary objects are created. Performance is key in this scenario so avoiding indirections not using variable containers looks good at first.

Simple calls like:

```
int slot= 5;
FPointer= ObjectContainingTheVariables.GetFloatVariablePointer(slot);
```

Comment: What's the difference between `PointerContainer c; c.FPointer;` and `float* ptr; ptr;` except an unnecessary level of indirection? Doesn't a simple variable do what you want?

Comment: does it have to a pointer? why not just a float?

Comment: Are you familiar with **smart** pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a more elegant way to do this without using a class?

Yes, there is. Simply use a pointer:

```
class FutureRelation{
    float* ptr;
    int FloatSlot;
}

FutureRelation connection;
connection.ptr = &FloatNumberInThe5thSlotOfSomeObject;
```

Note that copy initializing from uninitialized `PointerContainer` as in `connection.PContainer=somePointerContainer;` is... *pointless*.

Edit according to your note:

> Note: The FutureRelation objects are meant to be deleted once they are performed, so the pointer can't be stored on those.

That shouldn't be a problem. If you need the pointer after the `FutureRelation` instance is destroyed, simply copy it somewhere else before it's destroyed:

```
float* copy = connection.ptr;
```

Comment: The point is that i don't want to store the FutureRelation object. Those relations must work in a "execute" and delete way. That's why i think i can't just store the pointer in the FutureRelation object. Anyway i'm still thinking about all the possibilities.

Comment: @SaintJob2.0: How does `PointerContainer` solve that problem? It literally has the same semantics as a raw `float*`, lacking any methods.

Comment: I'm thinking about all your answers. It's taking me some time :)

Comment: @SaintJob2.0 well, my code works exactly as yours. So, if mine doesn't solve your problem, then your original doesn't either as MSalters pointed out. Not elegantly nor otherwise. I don't quite understand what you mean with `i don't want to store the FutureRelation object` after all, that's what you do in your question. Or what `Those relations must work in a "execute" and delete way` means, so I don't think I can help you unless you can rephrase your requirements.

Comment: Sorry. What i meant is that i want to create the variables/pointers to store the links (PointerContainer), then create the FutureRelations, then run those relations, delete them and end up only with the initial variables/pointers "pointing" to the new ones.

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify that the pointer can't end being stored in the FutureRelations objects.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`std::pair<float, int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) or a `std::pair<float*, int>`. No useless code, everyone knows what a pair is, double win. C++11 brings [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) which is also fine.

*nota*: see [`std::make_pair()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair).

Comment: STL containers should not be used to store references: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769781/stdpair-of-references

Comment: @jpo38 I'm so stupid sometimes. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Everyone knows what a pair is. But hardly anyone knows that `connection.first` is a pointer to a float and that `connection.second` is a slot of the float (whatever *that* means). I see no advantage with `pair` or `tuple` as opposed to a good, old fashioned, named class.

Answer (score 0):

If we agree you really need `PointerContainer` to encapsulate a `float*` (because I suppose it maybe encapsulates more stuff...), then a more elegant way would be to pass attribute values upon object constructions. To avoid `FPointer` (or `FloatSlot` from not being initialized).

```
class PointerContainer
{
public: 
    PointerContainer( float* ptr = NULL ) : FPointer( ptr ) {}
    float* FPointer;
};
```

Then you can do:

```
class FutureRelation
{
public:
    FutureRelation( int _FloatSlot ) : FloatSlot( _FloatSlot ) {}

    PointerContainer PContainer;
    int FloatSlot;
}

FutureRelation connection(5);
connection.PContainer = PointerContainer( &FloatNumberInThe5thSlotOfSomeObject );
```

You may also want to declare copy construction and assignment operator. But default ones behaves just fine here.

Answer (score 0):

Since you question is not a complete problem I will not discuss the design. However, you may be seeking something like this:

Make a free function:

```
PointerContainer make_container(float const& x){
    PointerContainer container;
    container.FPointer=&x;    
    return container;
}
```

And instead of:

```
PointerContainer somePointerContainer;
FutureRelation connection;
connection.PContainer= somePointerContainer;
connection.FloatSlot=5;
connection.PContainer.FPointer = &FloatNumberInThe5thSlotOfSomeObject;
```

You can write:

```
 FutureRelation connection;
 connection.FloatSlot=5;
 connection.PContainer=make_container(FloatNumberInThe5thSlotOfSomeObject);
```