# C++ vector of pairs of references to structures

Tags: c++, vector, reference, std-pair, c++98

I have vector of structures like this:

```
struct myStructure {
    int x;
};
vector <myStructure> vectorOfMyStructures;
```

then I push some (many) of my structures to this vector. Next think I do is declaring vector of pairs of those structures:

```
vector < pair<myStructure, myStructure> > *vectorOfPairsOfMyStructures;
```

the thing I want to achieve is declaring this vector of pairs to store only references to original structures in first vector (I will have line n^2 of those pairs), but following approach does not work:

```
vectorOfPairsOfMyStructures->push_back(make_pair(&myStructure1, &myStructure2));
```

How can I properly declare and add to vector of pairs of references of structures?

Why not duplicate?
1. I want to put references of structures to pair, not vector
2. I operate on c++ 98 (cannot use reference_wrapper)

Comment: not a perfect dupe, but the second answer can help you

Comment: I want to put reference of structure to pair, not vector itself

Comment: you also cant have a pair of references for the very same reason

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769781/stdpair-of-references

Comment: Well, the C++98 bit settles this then.

Comment: [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-api-4.6/a00887_source.html#l00422) you can find an implementation of `std::reference_wrapper` it isnt easy to read at all, but it can give you a hint of what you would need to write your custom wrapper

Comment: well I just realized that the implentation uses a pointer to the referenced object, so you might as well simply use pointers instead of references ;)

Comment: Will try with this