# How to return std::lock_guard in a std::pair

Tags: c++, c++17

When I go to return a `std::lock_guard` in a `std::pair` from a function I get horrible errors. But when I package it in a class I have no problems (compiles and works as expected). I can't understand why. Details follow:

I devised a small template class to enable convenient locking and unlocking of shared objects. It's not particularly innovative, but C++17 allows it to be very compact and code read/write friendly:

```
template <typename T> class Locked {
public:
    Locked(T& _object, std::mutex& _mutex)
        : object(_object)
        , lock(_mutex)
    {
    }

    T&                          object;
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock;
};

template <typename T> class Lockable {
public:
    Locked<T>       borrow() { return Locked(object, mutex); }
    Locked<const T> borrow() const { return Locked(object, mutex); }

private:
    T                  object;
    mutable std::mutex mutex;
};
```

It can be used like:

```
int main()
{
    Lockable<std::vector<int>> lv;

    auto [vec, lock] = lv.borrow();

    std::cout << vec.size() << std::endl;
}
```

My question is this. The `Locked` class is very thin. I thought I could use `std::pair` instead of a formal class, like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template <typename T> class Lockable {
public:
    std::pair<T&, std::lock_guard<std::mutex>>       borrow()
    { return std::pair(object, std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(mutex)); }
    std::pair<const T&, std::lock_guard<std::mutex>> borrow() const
    { return std::pair(object, std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(mutex)); }

private:
    T                  object;
    mutable std::mutex mutex;
};

int main()
{
    Lockable<std::vector<int>> lv;

    auto [vec, lock] = lv.borrow();

    std::cout << vec.size() << std::endl;
}
```

But this throws up horrible, hard to parse errors. I think this has to do with `std::lock_guard` not being movable, but to me, it *looks* exactly like my working code. Why does this second version not work?

Comment: I suspect this may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769781/stdpair-of-references

Comment: `return std::pair(std::ref(object), std::ref(std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(mutex)));`

Comment: @rsy56640 `std::ref(std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(mutex)` won't compile as `std::ref(const T&&)` is deleted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With some massaging `Lockable` does compile:

```
template <typename T>
class Lockable {
public:
    auto borrow()       { return std::pair<      T&, std::lock_guard<std::mutex>>{object, mutex}; }
    auto borrow() const { return std::pair<const T&, std::lock_guard<std::mutex>>{object, mutex}; }

private:
    T                  object;
    mutable std::mutex mutex;
};
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b1954e468cd0a73).

The idea is to explicitly specify `std::lock_guard` as a template argument  in `std::pair`, but feed `mutex` as the corresponding constructor argument (indeed, the second version doesn't work because `std::lock_guard` isn't movable). Overload (3) of [`std::pair::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair) will be used in this case.

(Also, since it is C++17, I would suggest [to use `std::scoped_lock` instead of `std::lock_guard`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43019620/8414561)).

Comment: Great answer - short fix and with an explanation!

Comment: For those prior to C++17: use the movable std::unique_lock instead of std::lock_guard

Answer (score 2):

> Why does this second version not work?

Among the [many *overloads* for constructing `std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair), your code cannot resolve to any specific one. Now, besides Dev Null's correct and straight-forward solution here, I'm leaving this for further reference: You can *forward-construct* your `std::lock_guard` alongside passing your `T&` the way you want to by using the `piecewise_construct_t` version of `std::pair()`'s constructor:

```
template <typename T> class Lockable {
public:
    auto borrow()
    {
        return std::pair<T&, std::lock_guard<std::mutex>>(
            std::piecewise_construct,
            std::forward_as_tuple(object), std::forward_as_tuple(mutex));
    }

    auto borrow() const
    {
        return std::pair<T&, std::lock_guard<std::mutex>>(
                    std::piecewise_construct,
                    std::forward_as_tuple(object), std::forward_as_tuple(mutex));
    }

private:
    T                  object;
    mutable std::mutex mutex;
};
```

Note: In addition, I changed *return type* of `borrow()` to `auto`, as we're being enough explicit inside of it in terms of what is being returned.

Comment: @SkepticalEmpiricist thanks for teaching me forward-construct!

Answer (score 1):

The significant difference is that in the first case, you pass the mutex, and let the result-type construct the `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>` on its own, while in the second, you construct it yourself and then let the result-type try to move-construct it.
The latter cannot work!

Luckily, the fix is trivial, just pass the mutex directly.

As an aside, consider investing a bit more into `auto` to reduce the noise.