# If there is reference in std::pair in c++17, is it safe and valid?

Tags: reference, c++17

I have a std::pair(or std::tuple) like

```
t = T()
std::pair<T&, int>(t, 1)
```

I just simply think it could have a copy construct less than this one without reference

```
std::pair<T, int>(t, 1)
```

I think it is valid but I wonder if it is safe in c++17?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [std::pair of references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769781/stdpair-of-references)

Comment: (Note the above goes into older languages, C++03/C++11 and so on, but the advice is largely the same). I know you cannot do this reliably with `std::optional` (and need `std::reference_wrapper`), but as for `std::pair` I believe it will mostly limit you from using `operator=` on the pair.

Answer (score 0):

- Is it ***valid***?

**Yes**. Unlike many container types, such as `std::vector` that requires a ***CopyAssignable`T`***, `std::pair` does not have such requirement.

Note, you will have `operator=`, the behavior is similar to using an `operator=` on other reference types:

```cpp
int a = 1, b = 2;
std::pair<int&, int> p = {a, 0};
p = std::make_pair(b, 0);
```

Above code will change `a` to `2`, instead of making `p.first` pointing to `b`.

Side note, you can use `auto p = std::make_pair(std::ref(a, 0))`, if you prefer using `auto`. Type of `p` will be deduced as `std::pair<int&, int>` here.

---

- Is it ***safe***?

**No**. Just like any other pointer/reference types, if the original object is not valid anymore, it will no longer be valid.